# Hibernate returns wrong date datatype (sql.date recieved instead of util.date)

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

[displayed error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMmbR.png)

As described above, I get the wrong data type when retrieving data from the database via Hibernate. I get a value of the class java.sql.date for a Date of Birth attribute of an object person that actually has the data type java.util.date, which in the course of validation (due to a PresentOrPast annotation) leads to an error because java.sql.date.toInstant() inevitably throws an error.

The mentioned Attribute

```
import java.util.Date;


@PastOrPresent
private Date birthdate
```

[Snippet of My Person.hbm.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwJCM.png)

I tried to set the corresponding attribute to java.sql.date, hoping that the conflict is because util.Date is expected and sql.Date is supplied, but this is not the case.

However, inserting data into the database via Hibernate works because at runtime the program instantiates the attribute as java.util.Date as intended.

But due to the error described above, an update including the validation of the data becomes difficult, as this leads to the error message above due to the error described.

I have also carefully searched the project and there is no import of java.sql.Date in any of the files.

Now the question, does anyone have an idea or clue how I can get Hibernate to pass the DateOfBirth value as java.util.date as it is intended and not as java.sql.date?

Comment: Try removing `type="date"` in your mapping. But really you should not map a birth date with a java.util.Date, it should be a java.time.LocalDate

Comment: @Guillaume Thank you, i tried it first with just removing  `type="date"`, this didn't work, then i tried it with using LocalDate instead of util.Date as you suggested. Both measures combined led to the desired success.

Comment: java.util.Date should be avoided when possible, java.time classes are a much cleaner implementation